# DatePickerRange set 30 days default time difference

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to have a preset data difference when you select the start date. It should be always 30days difference between start n end date either one you choose.

I am using the following [plugin](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options). But not able to get it to work.

```
<input name='campaign[date_range]' value='<%= @campaign.date_range %>' ui-jq="daterangepicker" ui-options="{
                          format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                          minDate: '<%= DateTime.tomorrow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>',
                          maxDate: '<%= (DateTime.tomorrow + 90).strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>',

                          <% if @campaign.start_date.present? %>
                            startDate: '<%= @campaign.start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %l:%M %p") %>',
                          <% else %>
                            startDate: '<%= DateTime.tomorrow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>',
                          <% end %>

                          <% if @campaign.end_date.present? %>
                            endDate: '<%= @campaign.end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %l:%M %p") %>',
                          <% else %>
                            endDate: '<%= (DateTime.tomorrow + 30).strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %>',
                          <% end %>

                          drops: 'up'
                          }" class="form-control w-md" />
```

Comment: you should use jquery datepicker because some method not working in anyother plugin.. but you can do whatever you want in jquery datepicker.

Comment: @Vishal are you suggesting to change the plugin

Comment: Yes.. because sometime ago i also stuck in this problem.. and after working whole day.. i choose to use jquery datepicker instead of any other plugin